# rich text editor not working on firefox

Tags: javascript, rich-text-editor

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Rich Text Editor</title>
</head>
<body onLoad="def()"><center>
<div style="width:500px; text-align:left; margin-bottom:10px ">
<input type="button" id="bold" style="height:21px; width:21px; font-weight:bold;" value="B" onClick="fontEdit('bold')" />
<input type="button" id="italic" style="height:21px; width:21px; font-style:italic;" value="I" onClick="fontEdit('italic')" />
<input type="button" id="underline" style="height:21px; width:21px; text-decoration:underline;" value="U" onClick="fontEdit('underline')" /> | 
<input type="button" style="height:21px; width:21px;"value="L" onClick="fontEdit('justifyleft')" title="align left" />
<input type="button" style="height:21px; width:21px;"value="C" onClick="fontEdit('justifycenter')" title="center" />
<input type="button" style="height:21px; width:21px;"value="R" onClick="fontEdit('justifyright')" title="align right" /> | 
<select id="fonts" onChange="fontEdit('fontname',this[this.selectedIndex].value)">
<option value="Arial">Arial</option>
<option value="Comic Sans MS">Comic Sans MS</option>
<option value="Courier New">Courier New</option>
<option value="Monotype Corsiva">Monotype</option>
<option value="Tahoma">Tahoma</option>
<option value="Times">Times</option>
</select>
<select id="size" onChange="fontEdit('fontsize',this[this.selectedIndex].value)">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<select id="color" onChange="fontEdit('ForeColor',this[this.selectedIndex].value)">
<option value="black">-</option>
<option style="color:red;" value="red">-</option>
<option style="color:blue;" value="blue">-</option>
<option style="color:green;" value="green">-</option>
<option style="color:pink;" value="pink">-</option>
</select> | 
<input type="button" style="height:21px; width:21px;"value="1" onClick="fontEdit('insertorderedlist')" title="Numbered List" />
<input type="button" style="height:21px; width:21px;"value="?" onClick="fontEdit('insertunorderedlist')" title="Bullets List" />
<input type="button" style="height:21px; width:21px;"value="?" onClick="fontEdit('outdent')" title="Outdent" />
<input type="button" style="height:21px; width:21px;"value="?" onClick="fontEdit('indent')" title="Indent" />
</div>
<iframe id="textEditor" style="width:500px; height:170px;">
</iframe>
</center>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
textEditor.document.designMode="on";
textEditor.document.open();
textEditor.document.write('<head><style type="text/css">body{ font-family:arial; font-size:13px;}</style></head>');
textEditor.document.close();
function def()
{
document.getElementById("fonts").selectedIndex=0;
document.getElementById("size").selectedIndex=1;
document.getElementById("color").selectedIndex=0;
}
function fontEdit(x,y)
{
textEditor.document.execCommand(x,"",y);
textEditor.focus();
}
-->
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

i browsed these codes online. yet i can't make it work on firefox. i've read some comments about this editor and it states it may be due to the iframe.

here's my source if it will be helpful, [text editor link](http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial198_Creating-a-Rich-Text-Editor-using-JavaScript.html)

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
    <head>
       <title>Rich Text Editor</title>
    </head>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function def()
    {
        document.getElementById("textEditor").contentWindow.document.designMode="on";
        textEditor.document.open();
        textEditor.document.write('<head><style type="text/css">body{ font-family:arial; font-size:13px;}</style></head>');
        textEditor.document.close();
        document.getElementById("fonts").selectedIndex=0;
        document.getElementById("size").selectedIndex=1;
        document.getElementById("color").selectedIndex=0;
    }
    function fontEdit(x,y)
    {
        document.getElementById("textEditor").contentWindow.document.execCommand(x,"",y);
        textEditor.focus();
    }
    </script>

    <body onLoad="def()">
        <center>
            <div style="width:500px; text-align:left; margin-bottom:10px ">
                <input type="button" id="bold" style="height:21px; width:21px; font-weight:bold;" value="B" onClick="fontEdit('bold')" />
                <input type="button" id="italic" style="height:21px; width:21px; font-style:italic;" value="I" onClick="fontEdit('italic')" />
                <input type="button" id="underline" style="height:21px; width:21px; text-decoration:underline;" value="U" onClick="fontEdit('underline')" /> | 
                <input type="button" style="height:21px; width:21px;"value="L" onClick="fontEdit('justifyleft')" title="align left" />
                <input type="button" style="height:21px; width:21px;"value="C" onClick="fontEdit('justifycenter')" title="center" />
                <input type="button" style="height:21px; width:21px;"value="R" onClick="fontEdit('justifyright')" title="align right" /> | 
                <select id="fonts" onChange="fontEdit('fontname',this[this.selectedIndex].value)">
                    <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
                    <option value="Comic Sans MS">Comic Sans MS</option>
                    <option value="Courier New">Courier New</option>
                    <option value="Monotype Corsiva">Monotype</option>
                    <option value="Tahoma">Tahoma</option>
                    <option value="Times">Times</option>
                </select>
                <select id="size" onChange="fontEdit('fontsize',this[this.selectedIndex].value)">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                </select>
                <select id="color" onChange="fontEdit('ForeColor',this[this.selectedIndex].value)">
                    <option value="black">-</option>
                    <option style="color:red;" value="red">-</option>
                    <option style="color:blue;" value="blue">-</option>
                    <option style="color:green;" value="green">-</option>
                    <option style="color:pink;" value="pink">-</option>
                </select> | 
                <input type="button" style="height:21px; width:21px;"value="1" onClick="fontEdit('insertorderedlist')" title="Numbered List" />
                <input type="button" style="height:21px; width:21px;"value="?" onClick="fontEdit('insertunorderedlist')" title="Bullets List" />
                <input type="button" style="height:21px; width:21px;"value="?" onClick="fontEdit('outdent')" title="Outdent" />
                <input type="button" style="height:21px; width:21px;"value="?" onClick="fontEdit('indent')" title="Indent" />
            </div>
            <iframe id="textEditor" style="width:500px; height:170px;">
            </iframe>
        </center>

    </body>
</html>
```